# Setting multiple cookie headers in Koa

Tags: node.js, http-headers, koa

I am trying to clear two cookies in my clients browser via the following:

```
this.response.set('Set-Cookie', 'mycookie1=; Path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; ,mycookie1.sig=; Path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;');
```

I can only seem to get rid of `mycookie1` and not the `mycookie.sig`.

Answer (score 4):

It's more about the protocol (HTTP). You should split it into two header fields (`Set-Cookie` for each cookie).

By [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-3):

> An origin server can include multiple
> Set-Cookie header fields in a single response. ... Origin servers SHOULD NOT fold multiple Set-Cookie header fields into
> a single header field.

There is a [better way](http://koajs.com/#ctx-cookies-set-name-value-options-) to set cookies with Koa than the raw way, two cookies are set by call it simply twice (see the docs for the possible options):

```
function *() {
    this.cookies.set('mycookie1', 'value1', options);
    this.cookies.set('mycookie2', 'value2', options);
}
```

Comment: OK one problem solved. However how is this done in nodejs/koa.